# Mapping all colors (except background) to a single color in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I have a spotty image. The image has maroon and black spots (with gradient) on a white background. I would like to convert every color (except white) to green color using GIMP.[image]

Comment: Hi user3392665, can you tell us what you have tried that didn't work? It is always good to show some effort. It also might be beneficial to upload an image of what you're referring to as well.

Comment: Hi AndrewH, I have included the image to the question. I tried using the "Fuzzy select" tool but only the maroon colored portion gets selected.

Comment: I imagine this is a raster image. If the background is pure white, you can do [Select By Color](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-by-color-select.html). If you're using the fuzzy select tool. I would select the white and do an [inverse selection](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-selection-invert.html) to select all the colors that make up the letters. I don't actually own GIMP but I imagine this is how you would do it. Someone can chime in if there is a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As AndrewH mentioned, since the background is plain white, you can select it and invert the selection, then fill it with the color you want. Here's how.

1. Choose the "Select By Color" tool and click on the white background.
2. In the menu bar, go to "Select->Invert"(the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>).
3. In the menu bar, go to "Edit->Fill with FG Color" making sure the foreground color is the color you want. If you want to still keep the original image as it is in it's own layer, create a new layer, then fill the selection.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Not the fastest method but imho the best.

**1)** Convert the image to grayscale.

**2)** Invert the image. You need a negative version.

**3)** Adjust the levels of the image (Colors > Levels) Untill you clean the image. The point here is to have a pure black, some aliasing and pure white.

[image]

**4)** Copy to the clipboard.

**5)** Make a new file with only the color you need.

**6)** Make a Layer mask: Layer > Mask > Add Layer Mask.

**7)** Paste the clipboard image there.

[image]

Not only you have a clean image with a nice aliasing, it is also transparent so you can play with it now.

Of course you now can flatten it to a white background again.